# Merging many columns in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sorting, merge

I have an issue with merging many columns by the same ID. I know that this is possible for two lists but I need to combine all species columns into one so I have first column as species (combined) and then w,w.1,w.2,w.3, w.4... The species columns all have the same species in them but are not in order so I can't just drop every other column as this would mean the w values aren't associated with the right species. This is an extremely large dataset of 10000 rows and 2000 columns so would need to automated. I need the w values to be associated to the corresponding species. Dataset attached.

Thank you for any help

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pwzC.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a frame called `dt`, you can use `lapply()` along with `bind_rows()` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(
  lapply(seq(1,ncol(dt),2), function(x) {
    dt[,c(x,x+1)] %>%
      rename_with(~c("Species", "value")) %>%
      mutate(w = colnames(dt)[x+1])
  })
) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Species, names_from = w)
```

Comment: This produces Species, value as two columns but how can I get all the values (w.1,w.2..) as separate columns next to one Species column? Hope this makes sense- thank you so much for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: you can swing it back to wide format, using `pivot_wider()`.. See my update

Comment: Amazing! My first time posting and you were so helpful, thanks so so much